# How to write XCUITestCase to drive an MDCMultilineTextField

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing, mdc-components

In a UI Test (XCUITestCase), when I try to let the test tap an `MDCMultilineTextField`, the test fails with

> Neither element nor any descendant has keyboard focus.

If I try to use the UI test recorder and tap the `MDCMultilineTextField` it fails to find the multiline text field with the error:

> Timestamped Event Matching Error: Failed to find matching element

My test-case

```
let descField = app.otherElements["EventEditor-TextField-Desc"]
let exp = expectation(for: NSPredicate(format: "exists == true"), evaluatedWith: descField, handler: nil)
XCTWaiter().wait(for: [exp], timeout: timeout)
descField.tap()
descField.typeText("Desc 4")
let saveButton = app.buttons["EventEditor-Button-Submit"]
saveButton.tap()
```

, where `EventEditor-TextField-Desc` is the accessibility identifier assigned to the `MDCMultilineTextField`.

When running the test, it fails telling `Neither element nor any descendant has keyboard focus.` and marks the `descField.typeText("Desc 4")` line as having the error.
Detailed error description:

```
Neither element nor any descendant has keyboard focus. Event dispatch snapshot: Other, identifier: 'EventEditor-TextField-Desc', value: Description
Element debug description:
Attributes: Other, {{177.0, 162.0}, {382.0, 78.0}}, identifier: 'EventEditor-TextField-Desc', value: Description
Element subtree:
 →Other, 0x6000020a7a80, {{177.0, 162.0}, {382.0, 78.0}}, identifier: 'EventEditor-TextField-Desc', value: Description
Path to element:
 →Application, pid: 61807, label: 'R+F Virtual Live'
  ↳Window (Main), {{0.0, 0.0}, {736.0, 414.0}}
   ↳Other, {{0.0, 0.0}, {736.0, 414.0}}
    ↳Other, {{161.0, 20.0}, {414.0, 394.0}}
     ↳Other, {{161.0, 20.0}, {414.0, 394.0}}
      ↳Other, {{161.0, 20.0}, {414.0, 394.0}}
       ↳Other, {{161.0, 20.0}, {414.0, 394.0}}
        ↳Other, {{161.0, 64.0}, {414.0, 350.0}}
         ↳ScrollView, {{161.0, 64.0}, {414.0, 350.0}}
          ↳Other, {{161.0, 64.0}, {414.0, 350.0}}
           ↳Other, {{177.0, 84.0}, {382.0, 282.0}}
            ↳Other, {{177.0, 162.0}, {382.0, 78.0}}, identifier: 'EventEditor-TextField-Desc', value: Description
Query chain:
 →Find: Target Application 'com.abc.myApp'
  Output: {
    Application, pid: 61807, label: 'MyApp'
  }
  ↪︎Find: Descendants matching type Other
    Output: {
      Other, {{0.0, 0.0}, {736.0, 414.0}}
      Other, {{0.0, 0.0}, {736.0, 414.0}}
      Other, {{0.0, 0.0}, {736.0, 414.0}}
      Other, {{-0.0, -0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}
      Other, {{0.0, 0.0}, {736.0, 414.0}}
      Other, {{0.0, 0.0}, {736.0, 414.0}}
      Other, {{161.0, 20.0}, {414.0, 394.0}}
      Other, {{0.0, 370.0}, {736.0, 44.0}}
      Other, {{370.0, -0.0}, {206.0, 736.0}}
      Other, {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 414.0}}
      Other, {{320.3, 0.0}, {415.7, 414.0}}
      Other, {{161.0, 20.0}, {414.0, 394.0}}
      Other, {{370.0, -0.0}, {44.0, 736.0}}
      Other, {{414.0, -0.0}, {162.0, 736.0}}
      Other, {{414.0, -0.0}, {162.0, 736.0}}
      Other, {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 414.0}}
      Other, {{320.3, 0.0}, {415.7, 414.0}}
      Other, {{161.0, 20.0}, {414.0, 394.0}}
      Other, {{0.0, 370.0}, {736.0, 44.0}}
      Other, {{414.0, -0.0}, {162.0, 736.0}}
      Other, {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 414.0}}
      Other, {{320.3, 0.0}, {415.7, 414.0}}
      Other, {{316.7, 35.7}, {103.0, 17.0}}, label: 'NEW EVENT'
      Other, {{161.0, 20.0}, {414.0, 394.0}}
      Other, {{0.0, 370.0}, {736.0, 44.0}}
      Other, {{414.0, -0.0}, {162.0, 736.0}}
      Other, {{414.0, -0.0}, {162.0, 736.0}}
      Other, {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 414.0}}
      Other, {{320.3, 44.0}, {415.7, 370.0}}
      Other, {{161.0, 64.0}, {414.0, 350.0}}
      Other, {{353.0, 378.0}, {30.0, 28.0}}, label: 'Toolbar Title Button'
      Other, {{414.0, -0.0}, {162.0, 736.0}}
      Other, {{414.0, -0.0}, {162.0, 736.0}}
      Other, {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 414.0}}
      Other, {{320.3, 44.0}, {415.7, 370.0}}
      Other, {{111.0, 15.7}, {98.3, 17.0}}, label: 'MY EVENTS'
      Other, {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 414.0}}
      Other, {{320.3, 44.0}, {415.7, 370.0}}
      Other, {{161.0, 64.0}, {414.0, 350.0}}
      Other, {{0.0, 44.0}, {320.0, 321.0}}
      Other, {{177.0, 84.0}, {382.0, 282.0}}
      Other, {{320.3, 44.0}, {415.7, 585.0}}
      Other, {{177.0, 162.0}, {382.0, 78.0}}, identifier: 'EventEditor-TextField-Desc', value: Description
      Other, {{177.0, 240.0}, {382.0, 58.0}}
      Other, {{177.0, 298.0}, {382.0, 68.0}}
      Other, {{0.0, -3.0}, {320.0, 146.0}}
      Other, {{0.0, 143.0}, {320.0, 30.0}}, identifier: 'UPCOMING EVENTS'
      Other, {{320.3, 73.0}, {415.7, 556.0}}
      Other, {{177.0, 297.0}, {382.0, 1.0}}
      Other, {{16.0, 27.0}, {288.0, 106.0}}
      Other, {{320.3, 73.0}, {415.7, 106.0}}
      Other, {{320.3, 219.0}, {415.7, 72.0}}
      Other, {{320.3, 331.0}, {415.7, 67.0}}
      Other, {{320.3, 438.0}, {415.7, 63.0}}
      Other, {{320.3, 541.0}, {415.7, 48.0}}
      Other, {{336.3, 73.0}, {383.7, 28.0}}
      Other, {{320.3, 331.0}, {415.7, 12.0}}
      Other, {{320.3, 348.0}, {415.7, 50.0}}
      Other, {{336.3, 463.0}, {399.7, 1.0}}
      Other, {{336.3, 469.0}, {399.7, 24.0}}
      Other, {{320.3, 348.0}, {415.7, 1.0}}
      Other, {{320.3, 397.0}, {415.7, 1.0}}
    }
    ↪︎Find: Elements matching predicate '"EventEditor-TextField-Desc" IN identifiers'
      Output: {
        Other, {{177.0, 162.0}, {382.0, 78.0}}, identifier: 'EventEditor-TextField-Desc', value: Description
      }
```

Platform

- Device: iPhone 8Plus simulator
- OS: iOS 12.1